# 12.04 - Are there any drivers for integrated Webcam on Dell Inspiron N7010?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dell, inspiron

I'm very new to Ubuntu. Are there any third-party drivers for the integrated Webcam on Dell Inspiron N7010, A work around, Or Canonical driver out there yet?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. It worked fine for me in 11.10.

Comment: If a webcam worked in 11.10, it should probably also work with 12.04 with the built in driver. It's unlikely that you need a third party driver if you hadn't needed it in 11.10. Ask your friend to troubleshoot the issue, and if he needs help, point him to the webcam troubleshooting howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing a program called `Cheese` in the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Then run the program and if your webcam works there is already a driver installed for this device.